# Laravel 5.4 replace file if exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I need to solve a small inconvenience that I am presenting with the update of an image when modifying the associated registry.

When I modify the registry I want to replace the associated file that is in the directory.

This is my table structure:

```
Schema::create('institutions', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')->unique();
            $table->string('initials')->nullable();
            $table->string('description')->nullable();
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.jpg');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

This is my update method on my controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //

        $institution = $this->institution->find($id);

        try
        {
            $institution->update($request->all());

            if($request->hasFile('avatar')){
                $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
                $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
                Image::make($avatar)->resize(250, 205)->save( public_path('uploads/institutions/' . $filename ) );

                $institution->avatar = $filename;
                $institution->save();
            }

            $updated = $institution;

            $message = flash('Institución actualizada correctamente!!!', 'success');

            return redirect()->route('instituciones.index')->with('message', $message);    
        }       

        catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e)
        { 
            $message = flash('La institución no se actualizó correctamente!!!', 'danger');

            return redirect()->route('institutions.create')->with('message', $message); 
        }   

    }
```

I have tried different methods but I have not succeeded.

Comment: What happens when you run the code above? Exception? 500 error? Please be more specific...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The image uploaded must have the same filename to replace the old one,but in this case it would not replace because of `time()` method.

You may delete old one by get file name from database and save new image

```
//find data by id
$institution = $this->institution->find($id);
$filename  = public_path('uploads/institutions/').$institution->avatar;
if(File::exists($filename)) {

  $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
  $filename_new = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
  Image::make($avatar)->resize(250, 205)->save( public_path('uploads/institutions/' . $filename_new ) );

  //update filename to database
  $institution->avatar = $filename_new;
  $institution->save();    
  //Found existing file then delete
  File::delete($filename);  // or unlink($filename);
}
```

Hope it would help